# regex for size ${word} - php preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

could you help me with the regex for the following examples:

```
lorem ipsum size large lorem ipsum
```

or

```
lorem ipsum size m lorem ipsum
```

or

```
lorem ipsum size 39.5 lorem ipsum
```

so in short I am trying to extract one word/string after the word/delimter **size** until the following white space. so in the above examples it would be (in order): large, m, 39.5.

Any ideas?

Quick update:
could you please include also a possibility of

```
size:$(size)
```

or

```
size: $(size)
```

or

```
size $(size)
```

Comment: Do you need to extract it or to replace? Use [`preg_replace()`](http://www.php.net/preg_replace) for replacing, [`preg_match()`](http://www.php.net/preg_match) or [`preg_match_all()`](http://www.php.net/preg_match_all) for extracting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$strings = array(
    'lorem ipsum size large lorem ipsum',
    'lorem ipsum size m lorem ipsum',
    'lorem ipsum size 39.5 lorem ipsum ',
);
foreach ( $strings as $string ) {
    if ( preg_match('#\bsize\b\s+(\S+)\s#', $string, $matches) ) {
        echo "<b>Matched '{$string}':</b>\n\n";
        print_r($matches);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Matched 'lorem ipsum size large lorem ipsum':
Array
(
    [0] => size large 
    [1] => large
)

Matched 'lorem ipsum size m lorem ipsum':
Array
(
    [0] => size m 
    [1] => m
)

Matched 'lorem ipsum size 39.5 lorem ipsum ':
Array
(
    [0] => size 39.5 
    [1] => 39.5
)
```

Size is stored in `$matches[1]`.

Comment: great stuff but what if there would be i.e. size:?

Comment: Like `size: large`? Then use `'#\bsize\b:?\s+(\S+)\s#'` as a pattern, it includes optional `:` after `size`. I also noticed that there's unnecessary `\b` after `size` and `\s` in the end, it may be just `'#\bsize:?\s+(\S+)#'`.

Comment: cool but nor working for size:large, must be followed by space to work

Comment: `'#\bsize(?::?\s+|:)(\S+)#'` will match `"size large"`, `"size: large"` and `"size:large"`. There is probably smarter way to do this, though.

Answer (score 3):

```
if (preg_match('/\bsize\W+(\S+)/', $subject, $regs)) {
    $result = $regs[1];
} else {
    $result = "";
}
```

`\bsize\W+` matches `size` plus one or more non-alphanumeric characters (spaces, punctuation etc.), but it doesn't match `capsize` because of the `\b` word boundary anchor.

Then `(\S+)` matches one or more non-whitespace characters and captures them in the first backreference (`$regs[1]` in this case).

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match('/\ssize\s+(\S+)/', $string, $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

Comment: I think that won't work. PHP doesn't allow infinite repetition inside lookbehind assertions. Or has this changed in newer versions?